# Quiz game in Netbeans - reading from text file

Tags: java, random

i am making a quiz game in NetBeans and i need a little bit of help. I want to read the questions from a .txt file and so the answers and setText on label for the question and radio buttons for the answers. I have a txt file layed out like that:

"1 Question..?"

"first possible answer"

"second possible answer"

"third possible answer"

"fourth possible answer"

"CORRECT answer"

"2 Question..?"

"first possible answer"

"second possible answer"

"third possible answer"

"fourth possible answer"

"CORRECT answer"

and so on..

I managed to create a string for each (question, first answer...) where i save the text from the file and it displays it for me in label 1, radio button 1,...
The program displays everything correct, but i am wondering how can i display each group (question,answer1,..) randomly and so that they don't repeat.

```
String question;
String first;
String second;
String third;
String fourth;
String correct;

private void jBtnStartActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

    int x=1, i=1;
    try {
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("questions.txt"));
        while(br.ready()){
            if(i==x){
                question=br.readLine();
                first=br.readLine();
                second=br.readLine();
                third=br.readLine();
                fourth=br.readLine();
                correct=br.readLine();
            }
            else{
                question=br.readLine();
                first=br.readLine();
                second=br.readLine();
                third=br.readLine();
                fourth=br.readLine();
                correct=br.readLine();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Okno2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    jLabel1.setText(question);
    jRadioButton1.setText(first);
    jRadioButton2.setText(second);
    jRadioButton3.setText(third);
    jRadioButton4.setText(correct);
}
```

Comment: What is the name of the class which contains this code?

Comment: What is the purpose of the `if-else` statement? You do exactly the same thing in both the if and the else

Comment: *"The program displays everything correct, but i am wondering how can i display each group (question,answer1,..) randomly and so that they don't repeat."* Create a class to hold both a question and answer (let's assume it's called `QandA`). Load the collection of `QandA`s into a list structure. Shuffle the list (to randomize the order). Iterate the shuffled list.

Comment: And `i` and `x` don't change, so doubly-weird. But orthogonal to the issue.

Comment: Now that I'm looking at it what are `x` and `y`? You never change them and only use them in the `if-else` that always does the same thing..

Comment: General tips: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) This has nothing to do with the IDE, don't include the tag.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you create a `Question` class which is **only** responsible for holding the question and all the answer choices. **Another** class can read the input and create a list of questions with `List<Question>`. Once you have a list of questions, you can randomly choose one of the questions. I suggest that you find a tutorial about lists to learn more.

You should keep the code which reads questions from a file and stores the data separate from the code which creates the user interface. As you continue to learn to program, you will gain more experience about how to organize your code to make it easier to write and maintain.